# Rails Resque workers are getting killed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I'm running Redis, where resque works picks up tasks from redis and executes it.

When i start the resque workers

```
COUNT=3 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:workers
```

I can see the resque workers are started

```
root  15347 95.8  0.2 268804 98844 pts/1    Sl   10:59   0:16 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake resque:workers
root  15383  0.0  0.0  67752 17860 pts/1    Rl   10:59   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake resque:work
root  15385  0.0  0.0  71872 18100 pts/1    Rl   10:59   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake resque:work
root  15388  0.0  0.0  67752 17856 pts/1    Rl   10:59   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake resque:work
```

But after few seconds, these works are getting killed. I tried using **VERBOSE** for seeing the log. But its not giving any error.

1. Is this a problem with redis or resque?
2. How to fix this so that i will not lose any data saved in redis?

Comment: What killing up resque memory issue ?

Comment: When i start resque workers, its starting. But its getting killed even before it takes any processes. I dont know how to debug this.

Comment: I understand ur point but there would be something thing that might be killing it and way I'm thinking is like memory issue can u confirm on that what does `free -m` stat show when u start resque workers

Comment: Hi problem was different, Resque worker was searching for a class, and that class was not available in my project. So resque workers hanged. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resque workers were killed because I have removed a class from the background job, and the resque workers were searching for the class.

When the class is not there, it has failed and was killed without giving any error!